# Insert query is not inserting values in the table

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to insert the values that i get from `req.body`. I save it in variables then pass them as values in the insert query. But nothing saved in the table.
Please help me out:

```
 var name=req.body.Name;
var CreatedBy=req.body.CreatedBy;
var CreatedDate=req.body.CreatedDate;
var ModifiedBy=req.body.ModifiedBy;
var ModifiedDate=req.body.ModifiedDate;
var email=req.body.Email;
var idAgency= Guid();
console.log(name);

client.query('INSERT INTO Agency (idAgency ,Name,CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy , ModifiedDate ,Email, Active ) VALUES (idAgency ,name ,CreatedBy ,CreatedDate, ModifiedBy ,ModifiedDate,email, 1)', function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(" not inserted") ;
    }
    else{
        console.log("insert");
        console.log(data) ;
    }
});
```

Comment: values other then integer should be quoted,maybe that is the reason. You get any error error?

Comment: how about a log so you know you are even about to get here (assumption being you are looking at console.log(err)

Comment: no it logs "insert" but in the table nothing is inserted

Comment: it   would help if you show where in the code you are calling this function. we  don't even know  if the code is ever executed.  what do you get in the console?  any of the messages  in  the error branch

Comment: to be sure, try to print query string you use in client.query and then  execute it in mysql.

Comment: does it also log 'not inserted' due to an awfully constructed query string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change insert query like below:

```
var name=req.body.Name;
var CreatedBy=req.body.CreatedBy;
var CreatedDate=req.body.CreatedDate;
var ModifiedBy=req.body.ModifiedBy;
var ModifiedDate=req.body.ModifiedDate;
var email=req.body.Email;
var idAgency= Guid();
console.log(name);

client.query('INSERT INTO Agency (idAgency ,Name,CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy , ModifiedDate ,Email, Active ) VALUES (''' + idAgency + ''' ,''' +name + ''' ,''' +CreatedBy + ''' ,''' +CreatedDate + ''' , ''' +ModifiedBy + ''' ,''' +ModifiedDate + ''',''' +email + ''', '1')', function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(" not inserted") ;
    }
    else{
        console.log("insert");
        console.log(data) ;
    }
});
```

Comment: *Please* don't build query strings like this, use placeholders or at least [the provided methods of escaping strings](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-identifiers).